# How do I unit test an Action Passed to another method

Tags: c#, vb.net, unit-testing, nunit, rhino-mocks

I am trying to unit test a method which has a line

```
_pollingService.StartPolling(1000, PollingHit)
```

Where PollingHit is a private method in calling class and signature of StartPolling is

```
public void StartPolling(double interval, Action action)
```

now whatever is inside PollingHit(), how do I test that ? Since responsibility of calling this method is on PollingService, but since that is not a class under test I should not be creating a concrete object of it.

Comment: maybe this could help: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/188609/best-way-to-unit-test-methods-that-call-other-methods-inside-same-class

Comment: I partly agree with this, pollingHit is a pvt method but its still defines behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test it though the public methods of the class which contains `_pollingService` based on the desired behaviour of that class. you can test polling service itself by just checking that it calls the passed action, it doesn't matter what that action is.

When you test polling service you should only test that when you start polling it calls the given action at the given interval. Polling service doesn't know anything about `PollingHit` method (as it is in a different class). To test this you could pass `pollingservice` a test method which implements a counter and check that the counter is incremented as you would expect. You can (and should) test this **without** the `PollingHit` method.

When you come to test the behaviour of the class that is using `pollingService`, you want to test its behaviour, regardless of how it is implemented. The fact that it uses polling service to call the `PollingHit` method is an irrelevant implementation detail, what is important is that the **behaviour** encapsulated by the `PollingHit` method is invoked when you need it to be.

Imagine if someone comes up with an 'push' based way of doing what you you are currently doing by polling (which is a 'pull' model) and implements a `pushNotificationService`. The **behaviour** of the class which uses the polling service should remain the same even after you have refactored it to remove `pollingService` and replaced it with the new `pushNotificationService`. If you test the behaviour only then your tests won't need to change after you have made this refactoring change.

If you are already using a mock `PollingService` then you can probably ditch that and use your own test double and use this to control the invocation yourself. Something like this:

```
public class TestPollingService : IPollingService 
{ 
    Action theAction; 
    public void StartPolling(double interval, Action action) 
    { 
        theAction = action; 
    } 

    public void TestInvocation() 
    { 
        theAction(); 
    }    
}
```

Comment: I can test pollingservice calling that method, but that method is private and is not called through any public method.

Comment: so do you suggest not to test behaviour of PollingHit() method ?

Comment: No, that is not what I'm suggesting at all. I'm saying don't test the `PollingHit` method in the unit tests for `PollingService` class, test the `PollingHit` method in the tests for the class which contains the `PollingHit` method by calling the public methods of that class and either verifying the state of the class or the interactions with the classes dependencies.

Comment: but that will not always be possible - to test PollingHit using public methods of calling class... coz in most cases PollingHit will only be passed to polling service and PollingHit may not change state of the class.. in my case it raises an event, how can I test that event was raised or not ?.. and its a private method that is only called by polling service

Comment: if your class does not have its state changed and there is no observable behaviour then your method does not do anything. you can delete the contents of `PollingHit` and nothing will chnage. So what it the point of the method? **Something** observable must happen when `PollingHit` is invoked. You said it raises an event. Can you not observe the behaviour that happens when the event is raised? Or have the tests subscribe to the event and check that they are called?

Comment: yea that's my original question, how to execute code under PollingHit() ? how do I create my test to  execute PollingHit().. as it is not called from any public method..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84483/discussion-between-sam-holder-and-muds).

Comment: As I said you do that by creating an instance of the class with the PollingHit method in it and then invoking the behaviour which will make PollingHit be invoked.
like calling a method on that class
or placing a message on a queue so the polling service sees it
or whatever makes the polling service fire and call PollingHit.
maybe if you elaborated on the class which contains PollingHit it would be easier to advise you